# Jquery datepicker How set class when onSelect date?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date)
            {
                ....
            },
            onSelect: function(date) {
                alert(date);

                    $(this).addClass('ui-state-custom'); //try one - not work
                    return[true, "ui-state-custom", "closed"]; //try two - not work
                }

            }

            });
```

I would like set class `ui-state-custom` when `onSelect` date (not `beforeShowDay` !).

Tell me please how make it?

Comment: What is the issue? that seems to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/8sQ5p/

Comment: @Jai select data in window datepicker should have class `ui-state-custom`. in your example it class have input.

Answer (score 1):

You should have checked the console for errors. little embarrassing to explain, its not `assClass()` its `addClass()`:

```
 $(this).addClass('ui-state-custom'); //try one - should work
```

highlight selected date:

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-state-active {
 background: blue;
 color: #555555;
 border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8sQ5p/1/)**

Comment: Do you want the class to be added on selected date??

Comment: yes i want make it, but class add to main div when found datepicker

Comment: I want to when I choose the date, class 'ui-state-custom' will be add to this date. see http://prntscr.com/3n213x

Comment: Updated the answer. check it.

Comment: how check this in your example if datepicker close after select date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54531/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-learner).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope it should be work fine.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date)
        {
            ....
        },
        onSelect: function(date) {
            alert(date);

                $(this).addClass('ui-state-custom'); //try one - not work
                return[true, "ui-state-custom", "closed"]; //try two - not work
            }

        }

        });
```

Comment: `return[true, "ui-state-custom", "closed"];` good working for beforeShowDay